# sqlalchemy join and order by on multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm working with a database that has a relationship that looks like:

```
    class Source(Model):
       id = Identifier()

    class SourceA(Source):
       source_id = ForeignKey('source.id', nullable=False, primary_key=True)
       name = Text(nullable=False)

    class SourceB(Source):
       source_id = ForeignKey('source.id', nullable=False, primary_key=True)
       name = Text(nullable=False)

    class SourceC(Source, ServerOptions):
       source_id = ForeignKey('source.id', nullable=False, primary_key=True)
       name = Text(nullable=False)
```

What I want to do is join all tables Source, SourceA, SourceB, SourceC and then `order_by` name.

Sound easy to me but I've been banging my head on this for while now and my heads starting to hurt. Also I'm not very familiar with SQL or sqlalchemy so there's been a lot of browsing the docs but to no avail. Maybe I'm just not seeing it. [This](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) seems to be close albeit related to a newer version than what I have available (see versions below).

I feel close not that *that* means anything. Here's my latest attempt which seems good up until the `order_by` call.

```
    Sources = [SourceA,  SourceB, SourceC]
    # list of join on Source
    joins = [session.query(Source).join(source) for source in Sources]
    # union the list of joins
    query = joins.pop(0).union_all(*joins)
```

query seems right at this point as far as I can tell i.e. `query.all()` works. So now I try to apply `order_by` which doesn't throw an error until `.all` is called.

Attempt 1: I just use the attribute I want

```
    query.order_by('name').all()
    # throws sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "name" does not exist
```

Attempt 2: I just use the defined column attribute I want

```
    query.order_by(SourceA.name).all()
    # throws sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "SourceA"
```

Is it obvious? What am I missing? Thanks!

versions:

sqlalchemy.**version** = '0.8.1'

(PostgreSQL) 9.1.3

**EDIT**
I'm dealing with a framework that wants a handle to a query object. I have a bare query that appears to accomplish what I want but I would still need to wrap it in a query object. Not sure if that's possible. Googling ...

```
select = """
    select s.*, a.name from Source d inner join SourceA a on s.id = a.Source_id
    union
    select s.*, b.name from Source d inner join SourceB b on s.id = b.Source_id
    union
    select s.*, c.name from Source d inner join SourceC c on s.id = c.Source_id
    ORDER BY "name";
"""
selectText = text(select)
result = session.execute(selectText)
# how to put result into a query. maybe Query(selectText)? googling...
result.fetchall():
```

Comment: Are you using [`inheritance`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html)?

Comment: print the `query.order_by('name')`, it might give you some clue.

Comment: @van I am using inheritance which lead me to believe that without any of the above mentioned code I could just do `query(Source).order_by('name').all()` but that fails because the 'name' column does not exist on the base Source class.
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "name" does not exist`

Comment: Right. And why don't you have this column in the base class?

Comment: @ralphinator80: OK, I got that you want to *order by* the name. To give you the best possible solution: a) what would you like the result of the query be? Simple `Source` instances (and children)? Or something else?

Comment: @van I'm using a framework that's expecting the return value to be a query that can ultimately run via `query.all()`. So the goal is to return something like `query.order_by(*columns)`.

Comment: This is on an existing table and moving the `name` column to the Source is on the todo list but the repercussion have larger implications that will just take more time. So this is the fix for now motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `coalesce` function is good enough, below examples should point you in the direction. One option *automatically* creates a list of children, while the other is explicit.

This is not the query you specified in your edit, but you are able to sort (your original request):

```
def test_explicit():
    # specify all children tables to be queried
    Sources = [SourceA, SourceB, SourceC]
    AllSources = with_polymorphic(Source, Sources)

    name_col = func.coalesce(*(_s.name for _s in Sources)).label("name")
    query = session.query(AllSources).order_by(name_col)
    for x in query:
        print(x)


def test_implicit():
    # get all children tables in the query
    from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
    _map = class_mapper(Source)
    Sources = [_smap.class_
               for _smap in _map.self_and_descendants
               if _smap != _map  # @note: exclude base class, it has no `name`
               ]
    AllSources = with_polymorphic(Source, Sources)

    name_col = func.coalesce(*(_s.name for _s in Sources)).label("name")
    query = session.query(AllSources).order_by(name_col)
    for x in query:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt sounds like it isn't working because there is no name in Source, which is the root table of the query. In addition, there will be multiple name columns after your joins, so you will need to be more specific. Try

```
query.order_by('SourceA.name').all()
```

As for your second attempt, what is ServerA?

```
query.order_by(ServerA.name).all()
```

Probably a typo, but not sure if it's for SO or your code. Try:

```
query.order_by(SourceA.name).all()
```

Comment: Tried you first suggestions passing a string argument. No dice.
`ServerA` was a typo should have been `SourceA`. Updated.
I don't see multiple `name` columns from the joins. I'm build a list of queries from one join on each child table with the parent and then calling `union_all` and all those individual queries which merges the `name` columns.